# What is the best way to ask why an old answer to a closed question is wrong?

Tags: support, homework

This closed question [Can the likelihood take values outside of the range[0,1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140463/can-the-likelihood-take-values-outside-of-the-range-0-1#:%7E:text=Likelihood%20must%20be%20at%20least,it%20may%20also%20be%20positive.) comes up when I search Google for "likelihood greater than 1"

However I recently learned in my course that it can not be.
How should I best ask for clarification on why the answer here, that it can be, is wrong?

Comment: The answer isn't wrong. You may have misunderstood what was said in your course. Notice further that the question is a duplicate, so click on the "**
This question already has answers here:** [Can a probability distribution value exceeding 1 be OK?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4220/)" to get more information.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @Kirsten you might consider removing the downvote that you placed on the answer that you thought was wrong but isn't wrong.

Comment: I didn't notice there was downvote from OP to the answer in question. While I won't dictate any how they would vote a post, it's a good practice, if there is a minuscule of ambivalence, first seek clarification and if that doesn't satisfy and is not rationale, then a downvote could be given.

Comment: When I try to upvote I get a message "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: @Kirsten I have requested Glen_b to make an edit to the post so that the downvote could be removed. If it is edited, you can remove the downvote (and may upvote).

Comment: I'm not concerned that the downvote be removed (as I had already let Kirsten know in chat); my concern with the downvote was identifying and explaining the issue that led to it (which between the comments and the chat I think has been resolved). However, I'll do as requested.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. I hope Kirsten has all the confusions resolved. And since the answer isn't wrong and the confusion has been vaporised (I hope), the downvote can be removed.

Comment: Downvote successfully removed and upvote added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's at stake here?

OP has doubt regarding the veracity of an answer to a question that has been closed.

Now OP needs clarification. What could be done?

$\bullet$ **Comment!** Seriously, leave a comment to the post seeking clarification re OP's concern. The poster, if needed, would surely respond or(and) might edit the post, if necessary.

$\bullet$ If the user is no more in the site, then still leave a comment behind, for there could be others who could notice and respond to that.

$\bullet$ **Ask a follow-up question.** Explain the concern in a new question re any assertion made in the answer to the previous question. But make sure to explicitly reason as to why it's not a duplicate. That is, it is to be asked with clarity why, at the very first place, the concern is legit and that warrants a different post.

$\bullet$ Also, one thing to be noted is to why the original question was closed: it was marked duplicate. So, one can resort to that question for more info.

Finally, one more I would like to add is that if a post is wrong or disseminating misleading assertions, chances are there would be responses from the community: it's highly likely the errs don't remain overlooked from the vigil eyes, if there is any error at the first place.

---

TL;DR: Interact with the poster airing the concern primarily by resorting to comment.

Some related posts across our sister sites in the same vein:

[How to ask for clarification of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128449/how-to-ask-for-clarification-of-an-answer)

[What should I do if I want more clarifications about an answer posted on an old question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110216/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-more-clarifications-about-an-answer-posted-on-an-old)

[Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer)

[How to ask for clarification on a very old answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14154/how-to-ask-for-clarification-on-a-very-old-answer)